# Questions about the o notation (Landau Symbol)

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

part of my current math assignment is about the Landau Symbol. I'm not sure how to go about in solving the following 3 questions.

1. $n^{s} \space \epsilon \space o(q^{n})$ for all s ∈ ℕ and q > 1
   Tip: You can use without proving it, that the derivative of $q^{n} = q^{n} *ln(q)$.
2. $q^{n} \space \epsilon \space o(n!)$   for $q \space\epsilon\space ℝ$ 
   Tip: You're allowed to use without proof that:
   $\lim_{a \rightarrow \infty} \space p^{n} = 0$ for $-1 < p < 1 \space is$.
3. $n! \space \epsilon \space o(n^{n})$

Now I was going through my notes and basically what I understood from them is that what this for example means: $n^{s} \space \epsilon \space o(q^{n})$ is that the part on the right grows much faster than the one on the left, and that's what I have to prove.

In order for this to be true, as per definition this has to be true (Based on my understanding): $n^{s} \leq  c * q^{n}$.

$\frac{n^{s}}{q^{n}} \leq  c$

Now I wasn't exactly sure what to do, but based on the hint I had, I thought that maybe I need to get the limit of $\frac{n^{s}}{q^{n}}$ which gives me $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$, and then using l'Hopital's rules further, but I wasn't really sure how to go forward or if I was doing this correctly, and what the point of doing the limit in this case.

Can somebody give me some direction on how I need to go about with this question?

Comment: Note that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{n^s}{q^n}=0$. The same reasoning can be used for the other 2 questions.

Comment: How did you get 0 from that? 

I mean as n approaches infinity, wouldn't it be ∞/∞? 
I know that the bottom grows much faster, but does that matter with infinity?

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^s}{q^n}=0$ corresponds to the definition of a function which is $o(q^n)$. What you understood is a function which is $O(q^n)$. One also says it is *dominated* by $q^n$.

$o(q^n)$ means more precisely that it tends to $\infty$ *incomparably* slower than $q^n$; the larger $n$, the smaller the ratio.

For 1, you can use *L'Hospital's rule* repeatedly.

For 2 and 3, the simplest is to use the *ratio test*.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I still don't understand my goal though... Ok so I get the limits, but then what does that prove? What is my goal here in getting the limit? I'm sorry if this makes me sound stupid, but all I have to go on about this is 5 minutes from the lecture, and 3 definitions on my notebook... I've never done anything regarding the little o notation before...

Comment: Equivalence of functions, $o$ and $O$ notations simplify the computation of  limits by removing irrelevant details.  To be effective, you need to have *scales of comparison*  for functions. The results of this exercise gives you fundamental components of these asymptotic scales. This is the goal of *Asymptotic analysis*. It is fundamenatl in computer science, to obtain estimations of the *complexity* of algorithms.